# $c_{0}$ is a nowhere dense set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

I am new to functional analysis and came across this problem. I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a feedback on my approach.

Prove that $c_{0} \subseteq c$ is a nowhere dense set.
My approach: Let $x\in c_{0}$ and $y \in c \setminus c_{0}$. Then $x+(y/m) \notin c_{0}$ converges to $x \in c_{0}$ as $m\to \infty$. This would mean $c \setminus c_{0}$ is open dense (because we already know $c_{0}$ is closed in $c$). Thus, $c_0$ is nowhere dense. Is this correct? If not, where am I going wrong?

$c_{0}$ is the space of sequences which converge to zero and $c$ is the space of converging sequences. The norm under question is $||.||_{\infty}$

Comment: Perhaps that, at least, you could tell what $c$ is, what $c_0$ is, and which norm you are using.

Comment: It is correct (with the usual norms on $c$ and $c_0$).

Comment: Easier argument: No proper subspace of a normed linear space can have interior points. So $c_0$ is closed and has no interior.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Updated the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your input. Perhaps the statement you gave may be trivial, but I do not see this clearly. Could you please explain why this is the case? Also, the proper subspace under question should be closed too right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Never mind. Thanks for sharing. I learnt something interesting today. I found a reference to your statement from the book Exercises in Functional Analysis by C.Costara. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, do you claim more generally: the complement of an open dense set is closed nowhere dense?  Can you prove it?  This is what you used in your proof.